# Equations to select pseudorandom number in a set

Tags: abstract-algebra, sequences-and-series, group-theory, number-theory

*I asked a similar question [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/413158/how-to-guarantee-an-id-is-unique-in-a-non-uuid-set-of-values) and it was recommended I check out group theory.*

Basically, I want to generate a string of numbers from 5 to 100 characters in length. The sets might be "every 5-number sequence" or "every 15 number sequence" or "every 100 number sequence". Every n number sequence.

Actually, I *don't* want to generate it. I want to most optimally find the next random (or pseudo-random) value using something like Group Theory! I can sort of vaguely imagine a way to use modulo to iterate through numbers in a set in a seemingly random way, and then at the same time *never encounter the same number twice*. (Or know if you are, and have some optimized solution to finding a nearby number or something).

Is there any way to accomplish this in Group Theory or otherwise? If not, that would be good to know to, why you can't accomplish this. But maybe there is an equation to do this.

For example, one thing I'm thinking that is better than a straight sequence is to go like a dampening wave. Say the set is from 100-999 (all 3-letter sequences). Then you would go:

```
100
999
101
998
102
997
...
```

That still doesn't appear random though, you can figure out that pattern in your head (even though I don't know what the *equation* is).

I would like something like that, where I can simply increment and index and have an equation to spit out the value.

Comment: I don't get what you mean by generating a string of numbers from 5 to 100 characters in length. Do you mean generating a number with between 5 and 100 digits by "random" without repitition? If so, I don't think group theory is even remotely relevant here.

Comment: Sorry, if group theory isn't a fit, then _any_ field of math. Which one would you recommend?

Comment: You might be interested in reading about the Lehmer random number generator: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer_random_number_generator (one of a group of generators called linear congruential generators).